# Does the spline between two points depend on other points that are *outside* the interval between these two points?

Tags: spline

Let's consider

[image]

taken from

https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spline#/media/Fichier:Exemple_de_spline_de_degr%C3%A9_3.png

Let's call the red points as : point 1, point 2, point 3, point 4.

I'm wondering if the spline part (the blue smooth line) between the point 1 and 2 would depend on the points number 3 and 4.

Said differently, does the spline between two points depend on other points that are *outside* the interval between these two points ?

Comment: Yes. With usual third degree splines, the spline coefficients are the solution of a tridiagonal system involving all interpolation points.

Comment: @Jean-Claude Arbaut : thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For sure the spline in one interval depends on the previous and next interval for cubic splines. See [this wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spline_(mathematics)#Algorithm_for_computing_natural_cubic_splines) on the algorithm to compute cubic splines.

Comment: It doesn’t just depend on the points adjacent to the interval, it depends on **all** points.